# PYObjC NSWindow is NoneType?

Tags: python, objective-c, nswindow, pyobjc, nsapplication

```
window = NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainWindow()
    window.contentView().addSubview_(chart_view)
```

The window was made in another section and appears fine but I get this:

> :
>   'NoneType' object has no attribute
>   'contentView'

Does anyone know why it thinks the window is "NoneType"? Thankyou.

Comment: Are you doing this after the nib has been loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `mainWindow()` is returning `None`, which suggests that there is no active window or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to connect the `window` outlet in the .xib?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've made the window programatically. No xib files at all.